# Oracle SQL error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How are you all?

Basically I've written up this bit of SQL code to create a table but I keep getting the error stated in the title, any idea as to why?

Here's the code:

```
    CREATE TABLE staff(
    staffID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR2(20),
    lastName VARCHAR2(20),
    addressLine_1 VARCHAR2(30),
    city VARCHAR2(15),
    postcode VARCHAR2(7),
    telephone VARCHAR2(15),
    salary DECIMAL (19,4),
    branchID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES branches(branchID)
    );
```

Also here is the code for my 'branches' table

```
    CREATE TABLE branches
    (branchID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    addressLine_1 VARCHAR2(30),
    city VARCHAR2(15),
    postcode VARCHAR2(7),
    telephone VARCHAR2(15),
    manager VARCHAR2(20));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions:

First make sure that the `branches` table has been created.

Second, I would alter the create table code to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE staff(
    staffID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(20),
    lastName VARCHAR(20),
    addressLine_1 VARCHAR2(30),
    city VARCHAR2(15),
    postcode VARCHAR2(7),
    telephone VARCHAR2(15),
    salary DECIMAL (19,4),
    branchID INT,
    constraint fk_branchId FOREIGN KEY (branchID) REFERENCES branches(branchID)
    );
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc945).  The syntax to create a [FOREIGN KEY](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php) during table creation is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
);
```

Comment: @blufeet is it possible to have more than one foreign key in a table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the creation of table staff1

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
staffID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR2(20),
lastName VARCHAR2(20),
addressLine_1 VARCHAR2(30),
city VARCHAR2(15),
postcode VARCHAR2(7),
telephone VARCHAR2(15),
branchID int,
salary DECIMAL (19,4),
CONSTRAINT BRANCH_fk FOREIGN KEY(branchID) REFERENCES branches(branchID)
)
SQL> /
Table created.
```

Please use constraint name such that finding an error becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table medication (
id int not null primary key, 
name varchar(20),
mudslig price number (10),
protect date not null default (getdate()),
finish date not null default (getdate()),
company proect varchre2 (20),
shelf id int,
chemistid int,
constraint shelf_fk foreign key (shelf id) refences shelf (shelf id),
constraint chemist_fk foreign key (chemistid) refences chemist (chemistid)
);
```

Please use constraint name such that finding an error becomes easy.